# Where is my System.Numerics namespace?

Tags: c#, .net, biginteger

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 and trying to use the `BigInteger` type in a C# program.  This type is supposed to be available in `System.Numerics` namespace, but I don't seem to have that installed in the .Net 4.0 framework.  When I type "`using System.Numerics;`"  in VS2010, a red underline appears under the "`Numerics`".  Has anyone else ever had this problem?

If so, how do you resolve it?  I just re-downloaded and re-installed (repaired) the .Net 4.0 framework, but that didn't help.  I've never had any problems with other C# programs that I've written, so I'm wondering what I'm missing.

Comment: Did you add a reference to System.numeric DLL?

Comment: A great visual answer of adding references (and seeing those added) is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9824530/910201

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You need to add an assembly reference to `System.Numerics.dll`

The [MSDN entry on BigInteger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.aspx) states:

> BigInteger Structure
>   ...
>   Namespace:  System.Numerics
>   Assembly:  System.Numerics (in System.Numerics.dll)

Comment: Doh!  That did it.  Thanks so much!  As soon as the timer is up, I'll mark this as the answer.

Comment: You save my day dude :)

Answer (score 3):

Though most assemblies are the part of the installation, VS does add only some core elements to the reference list of a project (Core, Data, XML etc.). One needs to add other references by hand using Reference Manager.

Right-click your project, then select `Add Reference` (or `Add->Reference`). `System.Numerics` resides in Assemblies. Then you can use `using System.Numerics;` in project files.

---

PS: this answer is not intended to get any vote. It is only for future reference if someone needs how to do it, just as I needed before this answer.