# Usage of System.Numerics in VS2008

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008, namespaces, dicom

Im using an open source code from [EvilDicom](http://evildicom.rexcardan.com/). Unfortunately, these codes are in VS2010 and they use the namespace `System.Numerics` and `Microsoft.CSharp`. I would like to know if there are equivalents of these namespaces in VS2008? My application is built in VS2008 and hence i'm trying to build in 2008.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.aspx

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4820953/where-is-my-system-numerics-namespace

Comment: @rahularyansharma i dont think i can use that, as the question is based on usage in VS2010, whereas i'm looking at VS 2008. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way the System.Numerics namespace is used is in the `UIDHelper` class to convert a GUID to a decimal number. It essentially writes out a 16 byte integer, created from the bytes of a GUID, as a decimal number.

I don't know how important this value is. You have two options:

1. You can replace this code with similar code that does not use the `BigInteger` type but is good enough for your purposes.
2. You can implement the `BigInteger` type yourself. There are several implementations, including in the .NET Framework itself, in the J# class libraries (See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163696.aspx).

Comment: Hi, @Jeffrey i do have a UIDHelper in my code. I dont think the first option is feasible as it probably wont be efficient enough (i guess, not sure!). Thanks for the second link, i'm going to look into it! :)

Comment: i was looking at my code, and i dont think i would need the UIDHelper and i guess now i wont need System.Numerics too. But when i build my solution, i get errors saying: system missing an assembly reference, even though my namespaces are all present. Im guessing this is because the code is using VS2010 namespaces whereas i'm using 2008. Any idea how i could go about from here? Thanks!

Comment: You should be able to just remove the references to System.Numerics and Microsoft.CSharp in Solution Explorer. I think Microsoft.CSharp was added to support the new `dynamic` keyword in C# 4.0.

Answer (score 0):

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.csharp%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) says Microsoft.CSharp namespace is available for earlier frameworks. Make sure you have added references to System.Core.dll and System.Dynamic.dll.

[image]

Where as [System.Numerics Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.aspx) is new for .net framework 4.0. Finding an equivalent depends on what you are using in that namespace. I am not sure whether there are any equivalents for [BigInteger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.aspx) and [Complex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.complex.aspx) structures...

Answer (score 0):

`System.Numerics` namespace was added in .net 4.0 and there is no equivalent namespace in lower versions of .net. If you have access to source code of this program and are willing to change it you could try to modify it to use [IntX](http://intx.codeplex.com/) library as a replacement for BigInteger if license is proper.