# Visual Studio 2010 - .Net Framework 4 Console Application

Tags: visual-studio, system, numerics

Basically I have added the System.Numerics reference to my project, and have added it to my using statements as below:

[image]

However, I am getting the following error:

```
The type or namespace name 'Numerics' does not exist in the namespace 'System'
```

This is hopefully a simple one!

Thanks

Comment: Answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4820953/where-is-my-system-numerics-namespace

Comment: @HarzIce The OP explictly stated that he did that and it's in the screenshot.

Comment: That's weird..  The "References" list to the right is for the same project?  Maybe try declaring a "BigInteger" and see if the little red underscore comes up in the IDE.  Does it compile?  Maybe the IDE just isn't refreshed..

Comment: Did you check there's no typo in the lines above `using System.Numeric`?

Comment: I feel rather silly, just had to re-build the program and it went away. Thanks for the suggestions.