# How to add a reference to System.Numerics.dll

Tags: c#, .net-assembly, system.numerics

I want to use the BigInteger class from the System.Numerics but if i want to write

```
using System.Numerics;
```

`Numerics` is not found. I searched the web, and I found that I have to add a reference to `System.Numerics.dll`, but how can I do that?

Comment: What version of .Net are you using? System.Numerics is only in 4.0+

Comment: hence `BigInteger` came with .net 4.0 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.aspx

Comment: funny that a lot of "answers" are telling him to add the reference when he already knows what he has to do.. he just wants to know *how* to do it...

Answer (score 34, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7314433t(v=vs.80).aspx

From MSDN:

1. In Solution Explorer, select the project.
2. On the Project menu, choose Add Reference.
3. The Add Reference dialog box opens.
4. Select the tab indicating the type of component you want to
   reference.
5. In the top pane, select the component you want to reference, and
   then click the Select button. Press CTRL while clicking to select
   multiple components.

Comment: I have Visual Studio 2013. How is it possible to not have this file? Where can I safely download it?

Answer (score 16):

Right click on "References" in the solution explorer and click on "Add Reference" as shown below in the image.

[image]

Comment: This is a great way to visually see what is added. Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

If you are using .NET 4.0, you can right click in References -> add reference -> In the .NET tab, look for `System.Numerics.dll`

[image]

Comment: I don't get the option to add reference

Answer (score 4):

in Visual Studio, go to Solition Exporer, expand your project, right click in a folder called "References" and click "Add References", browse the references (assemblies) until you find the one you want. If you're using VS 2010, you can simply type "system.numerics" on the search up top. Then just select the reference and click Add, then Close.

Answer (score 3):

Right click the `Reference` folder in your solution and choose `Add Reference`. Then go to `<systemDrive>:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Numerics\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089` (That's what it is for me; your path might be different.)