# C# Where to download System.Numerics

Tags: c#

I have a solution that requires System.Numerics.dll. I absolutely do not have this anywhere on my hard drive. I have Visual Studio 2013 and I cannot find a safe site to download from. Where can I get the DLL?

If anyone with a copy can post it on a temp file host that would be appreciated.

Comment: Do the answers here work? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9824479/c-sharp-how-to-add-a-reference-do-system-numerics-dll

Comment: Please try to use *google* or the *stack overflow search* before posting a new question. Second result when googling System.Numerics: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9824479/

Comment: Neither of you read my question. Where can I download the DLL.

Comment: You don't have to. It is part of the .NET Framework.

Comment: I absolutely do not have this anywhere on my hard drive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the .NET framework, you should have the .DLL file in your windows directory.

Mine is located here:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\System.Numerics.DLL
```

Do you have the .NET framework installed?

Comment: Thank you. It does not show up in my Visual Studio reference manager, and I could not even find it with a windows search. It is there. Thanks.

Comment: Next time use a programme like Everything to do a search of your hard drive, it is instant and pull up every file on your computer, much better than the default Windows search