# Why am I required to reference System.Numerics with this simple LINQ expression?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

To start, I know *how* to [reference `System.Numerics`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9824479/c-sharp-how-to-add-a-reference-do-system-numerics-dll) to give the compiler access to the `Complex` type it's asking for, I just don't understand why it's necessary.

I have this basic struct:

```
/// <summary>
///     Describes a single point on a spectrum.
/// </summary>
public struct SpectrumPoint
{
    public SpectrumPoint(double wavelength, double intensity)
    {
        Wavelength = wavelength;
        Intensity = intensity;
    }
    public double Intensity { get; }
    public double Wavelength { get; }
}
```

It is used in a class that needs `double[]` arrays to use as arguments to third party dependency.  I use this LINQy lambda chain construct them:

```
using Accord.Math;
// ...
double[] _wavelengths = points.Select(point => point.Wavelength).ToArray();
double[] _intensities = points.Select(point => point.Intensity).ToArray();
```

This is the error caused by those LINQ expressions:

> Error CS0012
>   The type `Complex` is defined in an assembly that is not referenced.
>   You must add a reference to assembly
>   `System.Numerics, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089`

I know this sort of error can be caused by unused method overloads that reference external assemblies, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20660999/the-type-is-defined-in-an-assembly-that-is-not-referenced-how-to-find-the-cause), **but neither `.Select()` nor `.ToArray()` have any overloads that refer to `Complex`.  What's going on?**

---

### EDIT:

This exactly replicates the compilation problem, which goes away if `using Accord.Math;` is removed:

```
using System.Linq;
using Accord.Math;

public class A
{
    public A(IEnumerable<double> d)
    {
        double[] arr = d.ToArray();
    }
}
```

([Here](http://accord-framework.net/docs/html/N_Accord_Math.htm) is `Accord.Math`.)

Comment: The code you've shown doesn't refer to `Complex` *or any other type*. Can you provide a short but complete program which demonstrates the problem? It's not clear where `Accord.Math` fits in at all.

Comment: Obviously the pieces you provide alone don't cause this error, so it's hard to guess. Create a minimal example (and when you'll be at it, you'll probably identify the problem yourself ;) ).

Comment: I copied your code snippet and compiled in VS2013, C# console applciation, no such error.

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses, everyone!  @JonSkeet, `Accord.Math` *will* be used for interpolation.  Everyone:  I've included more complete context where the problem sits for now, and I'm working on the minimal project to replicate the issue!

Comment: Okay, I've reproduced the issue now. I have an idea what it might be...

Comment: I've reproduced as well - see the edit.

Comment: That's still *way* longer than required - see the code I've just added to the end of my answer ;)

Comment: I'd suggest an edit to the question title though - you're really asking *why* you need to add a reference, not *how*.

Comment: Feedback incorporated!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I believe the problem is due to `Accord.Math.ComplexMatrix` - a static class with a bunch of extension methods, including:

```
public static double[,] ToArray(this Complex[] c);
```

I get the error with:

```
using static Accor.Math.ComplexMatrix;
```

...  but I don't get it with a similar `using static` directive for other types in the same namespace.

Changing your `ToArray` calls to explicitly `Enumerable.ToArray` calls like this makes the error go away:

```
_wavelengths = Enumerable.ToArray(points.Select(point => point.Wavelength));
_intensities = Enumerable.ToArray(points.Select(point => point.Intensity));
```

... which is a further suggestion that it's `ComplexMatrix.ToArray` causing the problem.

Basically you don't want to use any extension methods imported. Options:

- Call `Enumerable.ToArray` directly as shown above
- Remove `using Accord.Math` and fully-qualify any uses of types within that namespace
- Use a namespace alias, e.g. `using AM = Accord.Math` and then use that for any uses of types within the namespace, e.g. `var p3 = new AM::Point3()`.
- Use type aliases for any types you need within the namespace, e.g. `using Point3 = Accord.Math.Point3;` then you can just use `var p3 = new Point3();` as normal.

Now admittedly the compiler *could* potentially work out that that call was infeasible regardless of how `Complex` is defined, as there can't possibly be a single user-defined conversion from `double[]` to `Complex[]`, but spotting that would add complexity into both the language and the compiler.

Here's a *really* short but complete example that demonstrates it:

```
using System.Linq;
using Accord.Math; // Comment this out and the error goes away

class Test
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        args.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'll use the explicit `Enumerable.ToArray` and research `using static` (which I've never seen before).  That was some very fast sleuthing - thank you for the effort!

Comment: @kdbanman: `using static` is new in C# 6. I've added a couple more options you could consider instead of `Enumerable.ToArray`

Answer (score 3):

You can take a look at the [Accord.Math](https://github.com/accord-net/framework/blob/development/Sources/Accord.Math/Accord.Math.csproj) Project on Github as see that it references `System.Numerics`.  You most likely have some code that uses a `Accord.Math` Type that references the `Complex` Type, so you'll need to reference the dll.

```
<ItemGroup> 
  <Reference Include="System" /> 
  <Reference Include="System.Data" /> 
  <Reference Include="System.Numerics" Condition="'$(Configuration)' != 'NET35'" /> 
  <Reference Include="System.Xml" /> 
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: I'd expect there to be a need to reference it for anything hitting System.Numerics to work at execution time, but not necessarily at *compile*-time.

Comment: Right, but now that's basically saying what the questioner already knows - the OP is asking why it's necessary when there *doesn't* appear to be any use of code using `Complex`. That's why I've asked the OP to produce an example of the failure - I suspect they'll find the cause while trying to produce a minimal example.