# The type or namespace name" 'BigInteger' could not be found

Tags: c#

Seriously bummed by this. Wanted to give BigInteger's a spin, but:

> The type or namespace name" 'BigInteger' could not be found ...

I know how to add assembly references and such, but there is NO System.Numerics present at all - or then I'm completely and utterly blind.

How to fix?

Using Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015.

In project properties:

> Target framework: .NET Framework 4.5.2

---

System.Numerics is present (and selected) in Frameworks:

[image]

But still, even something this simple:

```
 using System;
 using System.Numerics;

 namespace CCHfT
 {
     class Program
     {
         static void Main(string[] args)
         {
             BigInteger b = 0;
             Console.WriteLine($"...{b}");
         }
     }
 }
```

...fails with the error message mentioned earlier.

Comment: SN is part of 4.5.2. Not sure where you're looking for it.  [edit] and describe how you are trying to add a reference to SN.

Comment: Well, it's in there, so double duh.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9824479/how-to-add-a-reference-do-system-numerics-dll

Comment: Right... and still, "using System.Numerics;" reds the crap out and I can't add a reference even as it's not in the list.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The type or namespace name could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764978/the-type-or-namespace-name-could-not-be-found)

Comment: The list of assemblies in your screenshot is totally different than the list that I see when I add a reference.  Somehow you're ending up in a different dialog - you're going to have to walk us through what you're doing step-by-step.

Comment: No, but that's "Add Reference". Duh.

Comment: can you give a bigger screenshot, showing the entire add refrence window? Also, add the content of your .csproj file when you open it with a text editor in to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out ... *facedesk* ...

Was looking at WRONG piece of a multi-project solution. No wonder fiddling with references didn't work when I was fooling around with wrong sub-project's assembly reference list...

Need more coffee... -.-

Answer (score 9):

It appears that you're not looking in the right place. From your screenshot you can see that you're missing a ton of `System.` assemblies, and the ones that are shown all have older versions. This looks like what you would see under the `COM -> Type Libraries` section of the References Manager window.

Try selecting `Assemblies -> Framework`. You should see something like `"Targeting: .NET Framework 4.5.2"` at the top, and `System.Numerics   4.0.0.0` in the list:

[image]

Also, ensure that after clicking 'OK' on the References window, that the reference appears under your Project Properties:

[image]

Comment: Edited my question... just before noticing this post. Target framework's 4.5.2 and System.Numerics is selected in the list, but still unusable...

Comment: What do you mean by 'unusable'?

Comment: @Sach nvm that - see my self-answer ... *eyeroll*

Comment: Very strange. Can you confirm that `System.Numerics` appears under your project references, as in the screenshot I just added?

Comment: Yea... but as you said, I was looking at wrong place - but completely different wrong place, wrong sub-project completely!

Comment: This is the best found answer! Thank you!