# How do I bring in numbers from a text file and do math on them in c#

Tags: c#, math, text

I am new to C#. 
I am trying to bring numbers from a txt file into my program and multiply them.
The text file would be formatted like this:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

I need the program to do `1x2x3x4x5x6x7x8x9x10=3628800`.

This is a list of 2 million different numbers.

I can get it to output to a text file, just not input.
I have looked around and can't really see an answer.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to multiply two million numbers all together?

Comment: Yes. I am trying to generate a million digit number

Comment: You will need to use `BigInteger` then, once you get the numbers loaded.

Comment: @Blorgbeard not just BigInteger but a BigComputer !!

Comment: Its taken me 7 days to generate the list I need to multiply so I dont expect this to be quick.

Comment: dont forget to mark my answer as answer 7 days later when its finished! ;)

Comment: [Your calculator is here!](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2000000!) product of number 1 to 2 million in mathematics is called 2 million factorial.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with few lines of code.

```
var lines = File.ReadLines(fileName);
var collection = new List<int>();

foreach (var line in lines)
{
   collection.AddRange(line.Split(' ').Select(n => Convert.ToInt32(n)));  
}

var result = collection.Distinct().Aggregate((i, j) => i * j); // remove distinct if you don't want eliminate duplicates.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
string value1 = File.ReadAllText("file.txt");
int res = 1;
var numbers = value1.Split(' ').Select(Int32.Parse).ToList();
for(int i=0;i<numbers.Count;i++)
{
    res = res * numbers[i];
}
Console.WriteLine(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var numbers = File.ReadAllText("filename.txt").Split(' ').Select(int.Parse); // Read file, split values and parse to integer
var result = numbers.Aggregate(1, (x, y) => x * y); // Perform multiplication
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to multiply 2 million numbers all together, but there is a problem.

The problem is memory limitation. to hold a big number you have to use `BigInteger` class inside `System.Numerics` namespace.

You can use this reference by adding Using keyword in top of your project.

```
using System.Numerics;
```

If the compiler did not recognize `Numerics` [then You need to add an assembly reference to `System.Numerics.dll`.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4820953/where-is-my-system-numerics-namespace)

Your code should look like this.

```
string inputFilename = @"C:\intput.txt"; // put the full input file path and name here.

var lines = File.ReadAllLines(inputFilename); // put text lines into array of string.

BigInteger big = new BigInteger(1); // create the bigInt with value 1.

foreach (var line in lines) // iterate through lines
{
    big *= Convert.ToInt32(line); // Multiply bigInt with each line.
}

string outputFilename = @"C:\output.txt"; // put the full output file path and name here

File.WriteAllText(outputFilename, big.ToString()); // write the result into text file
```

This may take a long time to complete. but this all depends on hardware that is operating. You may get memory overflow exception during this task which depends on amount of memory you have.

Comment: This is working so far, The only answer that I can get to even work without throwing an exception. Thank you for the nice explanations too.